# Parse the following XML using Retrofit SimpleXml-Converter Simple XML

Tags: java, android, xml

Do Inesessary need to describe all tags every time?
How can I take only text "340.00 гр" from

`<param name="Вес">340.00 гр</param>`

Try to describe next nested xml: http://ufa.farfor.ru/getyml/?key=ukAXxeJYZN

```
   @Root(name = "yml_catalog", strict = false)
public class OffersResponse {
    @Path("shop/offers")
    @ElementList(entry = "offer",inline = true)
    private static ArrayList<Offer> offerList;

    public ArrayList<Offer> getOfferList() {
        return offerList;
    }
}

@Root(name = "offer")
public class Offer {
    @Element(required = false, name = "url")
    private String url;
    @Element(required = false, name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Element(required = false, name = "price")
    private String price;
    @Element(required = false, name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Element(required = false, name = "picture")
    private String picture;
    @Element(required = false, name = "categoryId")
    private String categoryId;
    @Element(required = false, name = "param")
    private String param;
}
```

09-02 14:31:21.064 28998-28998/com.example.pavel.lesson8 D/TAG: onFailure: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.simpleframework.xml.core.AttributeException: Attribute 'id' does not have a match in class com.example.pavel.lesson8.models.Offer at line 23

Answer (score 0):

parsing in java is super, but the same parsing in python is excellent,my personal advice is to use python for html and other files parsing . Because , there are so many libraries were there to do your work easily and instantly

Comment: please post your answer and then a description.

Comment: But I work with android and I need parse xml for my app